# Raphael JS resizeable rectangles

Tags: javascript, html, raphael

I have searched on the internet , but I found no way to make resizeable rectangles in raphael JS; I am looking to make something interactive that can work both on a tablet so that's why the right click is a solution . Do you have any ideas that may help me?

Comment: Is this a technical question (how do I resize rectangles at all?) or a UI question (how do I create an interface for resizing rectangles that will work on tablets?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try with this raphael plugin? [Freeform plugin](https://github.com/ElbertF/Raphael.FreeTransform) ( [Demo](http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/))